# NSight graphics crashing "No Graphics API"

Tags: opengl, graphics, opentk, rider, nsight

I'm trying to debug an OpenGL (specifically an OpenTK) application using Nsight graphics 20.5.1
It's stopped working for some reason, and I keep getting this dump

```
Reason:    0xe0434352 / 0x00000001
Address:   0x7ffdddaf3b29
Assertion: Unknown assertion type 0x00000000

Thread 0 (crashed)
 [0]  KERNELBASE.dll + 0x43b29
 [1]  KERNELBASE.dll + 0x43b29
 [2]  0x7ffd381e0000
 [3]  coreclr.dll + 0x154a00
 [4]  coreclr.dll + 0x3b49d
 [5]  coreclr.dll + 0x156e78
 [6]  Nomad.Injection.dll + 0x71a6
 [7]  System.Private.CoreLib.dll + 0x39e2b0
 [8]  coreclr.dll + 0xaf711
 [9]  coreclr.dll + 0x66907
 [10]  coreclr.dll + 0x10be7e
 [11]  Nvda.Graphics.Interception.dll + 0x28670bb
 [12]  coreclr.dll + 0x10bd48
 [13]  0x7ffd381e0000
 [14]  coreclr.dll + 0x10b4b3
 [15]  coreclr.dll + 0x3eb830
 [16]  coreclr.dll + 0x3eb830
 [17]  independent-study-fall-2020.dll + 0xaf84
 [18]  coreclr.dll + 0x3ed970
 [19]  coreclr.dll + 0x51a690
 [20]  coreclr.dll + 0x3ed970
 [21]  coreclr.dll + 0x446580
 [22]  coreclr.dll + 0x10b402
 [23]  independent-study-fall-2020.dll + 0xaf9c
 [24]  nvoglv64.dll + 0x27c5d00
 [25]  nvoglv64.dll + 0x27c5d00
 [26]  coreclr.dll + 0x146c7b
 [27]  ntdll.dll + 0x3fba1
 [28]  nvoglv64.dll + 0x27c5d00
 [29]  Nvda.Graphics.Interception.dll + 0x2947673
 [30]  ucrtbase.dll + 0x114cb
 [31]  nvoglv64.dll + 0x27c5d00
 [32]  Nvda.Graphics.Interception.dll + 0x34fbf
 [33]  nvoglv64.dll + 0x27c5d00
 [34]  Nvda.Graphics.Interception.dll + 0xfaac18
 [35]  nvoglv64.dll + 0x27c5d00
 [36]  ntdll.dll + 0x3b9a7
 [37]  nvoglv64.dll + 0x1e55bf0
 [38]  nvoglv64.dll + 0x26d3680
 [39]  nvoglv64.dll + 0x26d3680
 [40]  nvoglv64.dll + 0x27c5d1d
 [41]  nvoglv64.dll + 0x27c5d00
 [42]  nvoglv64.dll + 0x8ee002
 [43]  nvoglv64.dll + 0x26d2ea0
 [44]  nvoglv64.dll + 0x27c5d1d
 [45]  nvoglv64.dll + 0x27c5d00
 [46]  nvoglv64.dll + 0x26d3688
 [47]  nvoglv64.dll + 0x26d3684
 [48]  nvoglv64.dll + 0x8ee0ab
 [49]  nvoglv64.dll + 0x1e55bf0
 [50]  nvoglv64.dll + 0x983ae4
 [51]  nvoglv64.dll + 0x1e55bf0
 [52]  nvoglv64.dll + 0x9853a4
 [53]  nvoglv64.dll + 0x6f10c0
 [54]  nvoglv64.dll + 0xe41d9c
 [55]  coreclr.dll + 0x154a00
 [56]  coreclr.dll + 0x3b49d
 [57]  coreclr.dll + 0x156e78
 [58]  nvoglv64.dll + 0xd4269d
 [59]  coreclr.dll + 0x66907
 [60]  nvoglv64.dll + 0x8d7f14
 [61]  ntdll.dll + 0x535a0
 [62]  coreclr.dll + 0x3eb820
 [63]  Nvda.Graphics.Interception.dll + 0xff11e6
 [64]  Nvda.Graphics.Interception.dll + 0x2036807
 [65]  Nvda.Graphics.Interception.dll + 0x35f50e0
 [66]  Nvda.Graphics.Interception.dll + 0x35f50f0
 [67]  Nvda.Graphics.Interception.dll + 0xed021d
 [68]  Nvda.Graphics.Interception.dll + 0x11a6a52
 [69]  coreclr.dll + 0x3eb820
 [70]  coreclr.dll + 0x3eb810
 [71]  coreclr.dll + 0x3eb830
 [72]  coreclr.dll + 0x3eb820
 [73]  coreclr.dll + 0x3eb830
 [74]  Nvda.Graphics.Interception.dll + 0xeac8b9
 [75]  Nvda.Graphics.Interception.dll + 0xeac8b9
 [76]  Nvda.Graphics.Interception.dll + 0x168288d
 [77]  coreclr.dll + 0x446288
 [78]  opengl32.dll + 0x30aa0
```

The Frame Debugger/Profiler don't work. The GPU Trace seems to work find, but also reads "Status: No supported graphics API detected"
I'm using JetBrains Rider as my IDE.

Any help would be much appreciated, it's a nightmare debugging shaders without Nsight.